# Unity Dependancy Injection passing runtime parameter values to a Constructor?

Tags: unity-container

I am using the Unity Container to inject a class into another class thru the constructor by passing the Interface to the Target classes constructor.  I want to pass arguments to a constructor of th injected class.  Can anyone tell me how to do this?

For example in the example below I want to pass a 2 parameters to the constructor of adminmanager which is being injected into MyClass.

```
 public class MyClass
{
    IAdminManager AdminManager;

     public MyClass(IAdminManager adminManager)
    {
        AdminManager = adminManager;
    }
```

}

Comment: Can you post the ctor for `AdminManager` as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can override constructor parameters when resolving an object via unity:

```
IAdminManager adminMgr = 
    container.Resolve<IAdminManager>(new ParameterOverride("param", myValue));
MyClass c = 
    container.Resolve<MyClass>(new ParameterOverride("adminManager", adminMgr));
```